# No tables returned from a SQL query. How could that happen?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Im having an issue with the next code:

```
try
        {
            OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=LuzDary;");
            OleDbDataAdapter Data = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Articulos", Conn);
            DataSet DSet = new DataSet();
            Conn.Open();
            Data.Fill(DSet);
            Conn.Close();
            _Articulos = DSet.Tables["Articulos"];
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

The try/catch is there because my VStudio 2010 installation isnt quite capable of detecting COM Exceptions somehow (Had the same issue creating the database with ADOX, the exception was uncaught, the code kept on running responsively somehow, but the DB was never written to the disk).

The DB already has the "Articulos" table, and i manually inserted some records there, but if i foreach the DataSet, i only get a Table named "Table". This is getting frustrating now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSet.Tables[0].Rows is what you want.

This is what I mean.

```
_Articulos = DSet.Tables[0];
```

With that, _Articulos.Rows should be populated with the records in your database.

Comment: To say it better, the table in your DataSet named "Table" is actually the table you want.

Comment: _Articulos is a DataTable, so .Rows wont work.... and neither [0] nor [Table] worked, still i get null :S

Comment: Still nothing comes up in the DataSet... i am sure the connection is right because the Access Lock file is generated when i step into Conn.Open(), and is deleted when i setp into Conn.Close() :S

Comment: My bad! The DataTable DOES have data, but my .NET 4 WPFGridView wont automagically generate the columns O_O

Comment: Oh, okay. After my last edit, I was at a loss as to what to try next. Glad you found it.

Comment: Now i find that my Binding suddenly broke.... ill have to make another question :( Thanks :p